# How to clean ashx url from cross-site scripting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

For example I have a handler `MyPage.ashx?parameter=1&parameter=2`

if someone added to the end of the url `<script>alert('Test')</script>`

```
MyPage.ashx?parameter=1&parameter=2<script>alert('Test')</script>
```

javascript will be executed on client side

Is there anyway to clean url from cross-site scripting?

Comment: Really? How? Are you pasting the parameter 2 value straight into the data returned unescaped? Is it HTML? If so why are you using an ashx, if not why does it execute?

Comment: yes I'm passing parameter. what is the better way to do it?

Comment: but anyway it doesn't really matter if I url has parameters or not. if someone attach the script

Answer (score 1):

The javascript is only being executed because you are outputting user input raw.

If your ashx needs to output parameters you must encode them suitable. Assuming you are creating HTML in your ashx page you need to [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) the parameter value before you output it. There are different encoding methods for particular types, it's hard to tell which needs to be used without more details of the ashx script.

Answer (score 0):

Check [ASP.NET Request Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx#paght000004_step1)

In addition to that you should never render request input parameters unescaped or unvalidated back to the client.

Comment: I have a handler, it's not applied

Comment: It is, as far as I know. See [how-can-request-validation-be-disabled-for-httphandlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332400/how-can-request-validation-be-disabled-for-httphandlers)

Comment: Check comments. Joseph said The "validate" attribute in the <add /> element has nothing to do with input validation.

Comment: It depends on the ASP.NET Version you're using. See [ASP.NET Request Validation](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147)

Comment: That's why. As you suggested ASP.NET request validation will work for aspx pages only with ASP.NET < 4.0. You're not supposed to rely on it anyway. You will need to validate/escape URL parts or parameters before you use them as a string for any kind of input or (even worse) output